# return more than one output on c#

Tags: c#, return

how can I return more than one type in c# function like I want to return string and datatable ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130372/c-function-returning-two-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own class to use as the return type:

```
class MyReturnType
{
  public string String { get; set; }

  public DataTable Table { get; set; }
}
```

and return an instance of that. You could use a Tuple but it's often better to have meaningful type and property names, especially if someone else is going to be working on the software.

Or you could use an `out` parameter on the function.

The way you go depends on what is suitable for your situation. If the string and the DataTable are two parts of the same thing a class makes sense. If the string is for an error message when creating the DataTable fails an out parameter might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is to use the DataTable's `TableName` property.

The more general answer is to use a `Tuple<DataTable, string>` or write a class or struct.

Comment: is this only in .Net 4 ? because I try it but VS2008 didn't know waht is tuple :S

Comment: @salamo: The `Tuple` class is new to .Net 4.0.  The `TableName` property isn't.

Answer (score 3):

**use ref or out parameters**

**ref parameter : requires initilization by the caller method.**

```
public string ReturnName(ref int position)
{
     position = 1;
     return "Temp"
}


public string GetName()
{
     int i =0;
     string name = ReturnName(ref i);
     // you will get name as Temp and i =1

}


// best use out parameter is the TryGetXXX patternn in various places like (int.TryParse,DateTime.TryParse)
 int i ;
 bool isValid = int.TryParse("123s",out i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an out parameter:

```
public string Function(out DataTable result)
```

Call it like this:

```
DataTable table;
string result = Function(out table);
```

Answer (score 1):

use a tuple as a return.